# Python, Docx, to replace soft returns (^l or manual line breaks) to hard returns (^p or paragraph marks)

Tags: python, docx

Some Word documents (.docx) that have soft returns (^l or manual line breaks).

When counting the number of paragraphs in the document, it shows there is only 1 paragraph (by script below).

What is the way to recognize the soft returns (^l or manual line breaks) and replace them to hard returns (^p or paragraph marks). So that the script can count the actual number of paragraphs?

A sample document as below, which contains 2 paragraphs. Using the code lines below to count the number of paragraphs in this docx, it says it has 1 paragraph only.

[image]

```
from docx import Document

def count_paragraphs(docx_path):
    doc = Document(docx_path)
    return len(doc.paragraphs)

# Example usage:
docx_path = 'the_file.docx'
paragraph_count = count_paragraphs(docx_path)

print(f'The number of paragraphs in {docx_path}: {paragraph_count}')
```

Based on above, I've tried below (to replace the soft returns to hard returns) but it doesn't work:

```
paragraph.text.replace('\r', '\n')
```

Comment: Could you explain the significance of the code provided, and what it does? There does not seem to be much context here.

Comment: thanks for the comment, @halfer. I've added more details into the question.

Answer (score 0):

From the Docs, https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/text.html#paragraph-objects

`text can contain tab (\t) characters, which are converted to the appropriate XML form for a tab. text can also include newline (\n) or carriage return (\r) characters, each of which is converted to a line break`

Hence I would look up the text property on each Paragraph and look for newlines and carriage returns. With a bit of testing, you could sum the paragraph count and dound newlines/carriage returns to get a correct total.